# Using grouby for counting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with the following structure (there are around 10K rows):

```
User Destination Country
123  34578       US
123  34578       US
345  76590       US
123  87640       MX
890  11111       CA
890  88888       CA
890  99999       CA
```

Each user can go to multiple destinations that are located in different countries. I need to find out the number of unique destinations users go to, median and mean of unique destinations. Same for countries. I don't know how to use groupby to achieve that. I managed to get the stats by placing everything in nested dictionary, but I feel that there may be a much easier way to the approach by using pandas dataframes and groubpy.

I am not looking for a count on each groupby section. I am looking for something like: on average, users visit X destinations and Y countries. So, I am looking for aggregate stats over all groupby results.

Edit. Here is my dict approach:

```
from collections import defaultdict
test=lambda: defaultdict(test)
conn_l=test()
with open('myfile') as f:
    for line in f:
        current=line.split(' ')
        s = current[0]
        d = current[1]
        if conn_l[s][d]:
            conn_l[s][d]+=1
        else:
            conn_l[s][d]=1

lengths=[]
for k,v in conn_l.items():
    lengths.append(len(v))
```

Comment: Can you post your efforts, the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) and [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html) as well as here have examples that will help you

Comment: Without wanting to be a jerk about it, this looks eminently Googlable. There should be plenty of advice on this site already about counting elements of a `groupby`.

Comment: I added my code. Yes, I know how to use groupby, but I somehow keep failing in calculating the stats for each group.

Comment: Also, I am not looking for stats on each groupby, but aggregate over all groupy results. So, on average a user goes to X destinations and Y countries. Mean is and max is etc.

Comment: Note:  I added some rows to the sample data to make it easier to check result.  Please re-edit it to your liking, if necessary.

Comment: @EdChum, LondonRob  I decided to give an anwer here b/c it didn't look  like either of you was going to do it.  I see what you guys are saying but I think by recent SO standards this was a reasonable question and no one had given an answer after it had received 35 views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one might be a little harder than it looks at first glance (or perhaps there is a simpler approach than what I do below).

```
ser = df.groupby('User')['Destination'].value_counts()

123   34578    2
      87640    1
345   76590    1
890   11111    1
      99999    1
      88888    1
```

The output of `value_counts()` is a series, you can then do groupby a second time to get a count of the unique destinations.

```
ser2 = ser.groupby(level=0).count()

User
123    2
345    1
890    3
```

That's for clarity but you could do it all on one line.

```
df.groupby('User')['Destination'].value_counts().groupby(level=0).count()
```

With ser2 you ought to be able to do all the other things.

```
ser2.median()
ser2.mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with JohnE that counting the number of entries for User is not obvious.
I found that:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['User','Destination'])
df3 = df2.size().groupby(level=0).count()
```

also works, the only difference being that df2 is a Dataframe.groupby rather than a series.groupby, so potentially has a bit more functionality since it retains the Country information.

A trivial example:

```
for name, group in df2:
    print name, group

    (123, 34578)    User  Destination Country
0   123        34578      US
1   123        34578      US
(123, 87640)    User  Destination Country
3   123        87640      MX
(345, 76590)    User  Destination Country
2   345        76590      US
(890, 11111)    User  Destination Country
4   890        11111      CA
(890, 88888)    User  Destination Country
5   890        88888      CA
(890, 99999)    User  Destination Country
6   890        99999      CA

ser = df.groupby('User')['Destination']
for name, group in ser:
    print name, group

123 0    34578
1    34578
3    87640
Name: Destination, dtype: int64
345 2    76590
Name: Destination, dtype: int64
890 4    11111
5    88888
6    99999
Name: Destination, dtype: int64
```